# How to structure constant values

Tags: c#

I want to organize a set of constants...

Method 1:

```
class Constants
{
    public const int A_B_C = 1;
    public const string A_B_D = "test";
}
var x = Constants.A_B_D;
```

Method 2:

```
class Constants
{
    public static readonly A A = new A();
}
class A
{
    public static readonly B B = new B();
}
class B
{
    public static const int C = 1;
    public static const string D = "test";
}
var x = Constants.A.B.D;
```

And I want to know... Is there a way to simplify `Method 2` reducing the code...? Some syntactic sugar to declare it like JSON or something like that?

Pseudocode:

```
class Constants
{
    public static readonly [datatype] A =
    {
        public static readonly [datatype] B =
        {
            public const int C = 1;
            public const string D = "test";
        };
    };
}
```

Comment: Why are you creating an instance of `B` when it only contains `static`/`const` members? You can access those without any instance

Comment: classes can contain classes...

Comment: I mean, you could just do `static class Constants { static class A { static class B { const int C = 1; const string D = "test"; } } }` If you wanted...

Comment: Maybe just use a JSON file and read/write to it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like **nested classes** fit the bill for this:

```
namespace Constants
{
    public static class A
    {
        public static class B
        {
            public const int C = 1;

            public const string D = "test";
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since they are all constant i don't see why you need then to be classes. You can use struct without having to rely on static

```
namespace Constants
{
    public struct A
    {
        public struct  B
        {
            public const int C = 1;

            public const string D = "test";
        }
    }
}
```

and call it like this

```
var c = Constants.A.B.C;
```

Comment: You're right about the classes. That was the reason why I asked if there is a simpler way to declare the constants. With your solution someone could create an instance of `B` with `new A.B()` so I think I'd go with the nested `static class`es

Comment: @Michael indeed you could by why would you ? The structs are empty.

Comment: Why is it better to use structs vs. classes?

Comment: @KlausGütter in that specific case the only difference i see is the memory footprint. Should be 128 bits smaller with `struct`. But depends how many `class` you use. Right now only 2 are used so i assume 2 extra 64bits pointers

Comment: static class should have no overhead.

Comment: @KlausGütter a `class` is a reference type hence an extra pointer. [See MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/classes)

Comment: @Franck Yes, per instance. But static classes have no instances.